# Validating a form when either a "select" OR "input" is required

Tags: javascript, validation, html-select, html-input

I have a page containing multiple forms, all different, and when one is submitted I use the function below to gather all the inputs from that form with the class "required" and check for empty values:

```
function validateForm(form) {
  var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var selects = form.getElementsByTagName('select');
  var errors = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].classList.contains('required')) {    
      if(inputs[i].value === "") {
        inputs[i].classList.add("warning");
        errors++;
      } else {
        inputs[i].classList.remove("warning");
      }
    }
  }
  if(errors) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

If it finds an empty value, it adds the class "warning" which just gives the input a red border, then returns false so the form doesn't get submitted.

Here's where I'm running into trouble: Some forms contain a <select> and a text input, ONE of which must be filled in, but not both, as well as various other text inputs.  I'm trying to figure out how to modify the above function to handle this.

Let's say the form is for adding a new product. The select is dynamically populated with existing product "categories" and the text input is for if the user wants to create a new category.  Here's a simplified version of the form:

```
    <form method = "post" onsubmit = "return validateForm(this)">
      <div class = "form-group">
        <label>Product Name</label>
        <input class = "form-control required" type = "text" name = "product" />
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <select class = "form-control required" id = "category" name = "category[]">
          <option value = "">Select Existing Category</option>
          <option value = "Shirts">Shirts</option>
          <option value = "Shoes">Shoes</option>
          <option value = "Pants">Pants</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <label>Create New Category</label>
        <input class = "form-control required" type = "text" name = "category[]" />
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <input class = "btn btn-primary" type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
```

Since I'm using a for loop to go through the inputs - the select and the input are not going to have the same index, so I can't do something like this:

```
  if((selects[i].value === "" && inputs[i].value === "") || (selects[i].value !== "" && inputs[i].value !== "")) {
    // add the warning class to both
   }
```

I feel the answer lies somewhere in using the name attribute, i.e. compare selects.name and inputs.name, but how do I get around the differing index in the loop? And also, it should only make this comparison when the select is encountered anyway. It doesn't necessarily exist, depending on the form.

Basically, I need to modify my function to do this:

I. Gather all inputs and selects (if any - some forms will not) from a submitted form

II. Make sure none of the inputs with the "required" class are blank (unless there's a corresponding select, in which case see III below)

III. If there's a select, find the text input with the same "name" (not a requirement to have the same name, but I assume this is the right way to do it). One of them, but not both, must have a value. If both are blank, or both have a value, they should get the "warning" class;

Any help anyone can offer will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you use a 'data-*' attribute to specify the alternate element.  Then change the function to check for that data attribute.  If the attribute isn't found then that means the element is required.  If the data attribute is found then use it to check the other element.  So, both the 'input' and 'select' will still have a class of required but your function can check the data attribute.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @CharlesEF I THINK I know what you mean: Add a matching 'data-*' attribute value to the select/input pair, then in my loop add some code to check if an input has that attribute, and if so, look for the select with a data attribute of matching value, then compare their values? How would I "find" the select with the same data attribute value though?

Comment: `form.elements[theName]` is pretty old-school or `document.querySelector("[name='" + theName + "']")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that do exactly what you want and can handle any form you want, as long as they have the same `HTML` structure.

**Notes:**

- I recommend avoiding inline event listeners as much as you can, in
  the snippet below I used `addEventListener` method to attach `submit`
  event to all the forms in the document, you can change this to just
  some specific forms if you want.
- Instead of only adding a border to the required elements, I suggest
  you also add some text to tell what the problem is.

```js
// getting all forms in the page you can also get specific forms based on their class-name
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form'),
  l = forms.length,
  i = 0;
// adding submit submit event listener to the referenced forms
for(; i < l; i++) {
  forms[i].addEventListener('submit', validateForm);
}


function validateForm(e) {
  var els = this.querySelectorAll('input.required'),
    len = els.length,
    err = false,
    c = 0,
    inpName = '';
  // checking if the form has a select, if so, allow only the select or the input to be filled
  var isSelect = this.getElementsByTagName('select');
  if(isSelect[0] !== undefined && isSelect[0] !== null) {
    var inp = isSelect[0].parentNode.nextElementSibling.querySelector('input.required');
    inpName = inp.name;
    if((isSelect[0].value == '' && inp.value.trim().length === 0) || (isSelect[0].value != '' && inp.value.trim().length > 0)) {
      err = true;
      isSelect[0].classList.add("warning");
      inp.classList.add("warning");
    } else {
      isSelect[0].classList.remove("warning");
      inp.classList.remove("warning");
    }
  }

  // iterate through the rest of the inputs and check for empty one, thus trimming them before checking
  for(; c < len; c++) {
    if(els[c].name !== inpName) {
      if(els[c].value.trim() == '') {
        err = true;
        els[c].classList.add("warning");
      } else {
        els[c].classList.remove("warning");
      }
    }
  }
  // based on the error variable, either submit the form or cancel submission
  (!err) ? this.submit():e.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
.warning {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Product Name</label>
        <input class="form-control required" type="text" name="product" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control required" id="category" name="category[]">
            <option value="">Select Existing Category</option>
            <option value="Shirts">Shirts</option>
            <option value="Shoes">Shoes</option>
            <option value="Pants">Pants</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Create New Category</label>
        <input class="form-control required" type="text" name="category[]" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Hope I pushed you further.

> You may get a message saying: "The custom error module does not
>   recognize this error." when you successfully submit the form from the
>   snippet above, that due to `StackOverflow`'s restrictions as they
>   don't allow/server side code (`StackOverflow` doesn't let the form to
>   be submitted).

Comment: Wow, you're right, that does exactly what I want, lol. Thank you so much. It's  definitely more advanced than what I could have written myself, but I'm picking it apart line by line to understand each step. Definitely a great learning experience. Thanks again!

Comment: @JohnO you're welcome at any time. Let me hear if you want some further explanations. But, keep in mind I didn't got much details from you, so I implemented my answer based on the structure of the form that you provided in the question, thus changing the form structure may lead to malfunction. And again, need any help let me hear.

Comment: Thanks for the offer and I will let you know! I'm still going through it line by line now. It makes sense when I follow it but yeah...I definitely couldn't have written this myself. I need to brush up on my JavaScript lol.

Comment: we all still learning. Take your time, I added some comments to the code, they may help you.